# RST, ACK - DB to web server

Tags: azure, networking, wireshark

We have a situation where a vendor is blaming our network connection (over s2s VPN) between the database (Azure) and web server (on-premises).

The db was just upgraded by the vendor from Oracle 10g to 12c and moved Azure.

I performed a packet capture using our firewall with the database as the source and web server as the dest. I've been reading about timeouts, keep-alives and resets but am still having some difficulty analyzing the packet captures.

Ultimately we're trying to determine if it is the network connection causing issues. Ping tests over the VPN with over 1000 byte packets/3600 count don't drop a single packet and avg 25ms.

Analyzing the captures I came across a [RST, ACK] (expert info (warn/sequence) connection reset) with the source db and dest web server. This comes right after a Data Request from the web server to db. Does this indicate a problem with the db? Wireshark indicates this is a serious problem (error/e.g. malformed packet).

[image: capture]

Answer (score 0):

A TCP RST is shown as bold red by wireshark, so we might think its a 'bad' thing. But actually a TCP RST can be good-or-bad depending on how and when they happen.

The polite way to closing a TCP connection is FIN, but a talk-to-the-hand way is RST. If the RST is seen at the end of TCP conversation, it could simply be a means of cleaning up (depending on configuration of stack). If the RST happens mid-way, then it is a reason to worry. It could be a result of load-balancer, firewall or router in the middle that is timing the connection out prematurely or can be application problem on server side(db in your case).

It might be useful to check the TTL indicating how many routes the reset has traveled, which might indicate that RST source may not be source IP. It is hard to give a simple answer, but you need to dig deeper to understand TCP RST.

Comment: Thank you for the info Ketan. Much appreciated.